# Sql query to auto assign row level data.. Please see the condition in the body of the requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can this group please me brainstorm ideas to **write a sql query** for the condition listed below.

- The item listed below are the accounts with the collection amount per each account.
- Let say there are 4 people ( A, B C D) and each people should be assigned the  average of total collection amount. (ie 8190/4 = 2047.5 ) or smthing around this value. ( In reality there will be hundered of people collecting thousands of collection accounts)

  ```
  Accounts #            Collection Amount 
  1 25X1                   $800.00 
  1 25X2                   $200.00 
  1 25X3                   $700.00 
  1 25X4                   $120.00 
  1 25X5                   $500.00 
  1 25X6                   $410.00 
  1 25X7                   $800.00 
  1 25X8                   $200.00 
  1 25X9                   $700.00 
  1 25X10                  $120.00 
  1 25X11                  $500.00 
  1 25X12                  $410.00 
  1 25X13                  $800.00 
  1 25X14                  $200.00 
  1 25X15                  $700.00 
  1 25X16                  $120.00 
  1 25X17                  $500.00 
  1 25X18                  $410.00 
  Total Collection       $8,190.00
  ```

Comment: sql server is the one

Comment: Okay, here's one idea - order the accounts by amount (descending), divvy them up by adding the highest-remaining amount to the person with the lowest current total, continue until the amounts are exhausted.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Where are people in your data? What is the desired output?

Comment: My aim is to write a SQL query which will auto assign accounts to each person with equal collection amount

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "people" are each individual account holder:

```
SELECT [Accounts #]
,[Collection Amount]
,(SELECT SUM([Collection Amount])/COUNT(distinct [Accounts #]) as AverageCollection 
FROM [TableName])
```